# PLSQL: Change first two digits of year

Tags: sql, plsql

Some of the dates in a date column have an incorrect year.  How do I change the first two digits of the year?

For example:

```
select 
ID,
to_char(END_DT,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') as dt
From DB
```

Would result:

```
ID   dt
1    0207-08-10 12:00:00
2    0208-03-31 12:00:00
3    0200-11-10 12:00:00
```

I want the results to look like this:

```
ID   dt
1    2007-08-10 12:00:00
2    2008-03-31 12:00:00
3    2000-11-10 12:00:00
```

Comment: I don't think your problem is how the date looks in a SELECT query.  Your problem is that the date is stored incorrectly.  You need to update the column to have correct date values.

Comment: show us the output of `select END_DT from DB` and also, the column-type and how do you `INSERT`

Comment: Why are you attempting to get a formatted _string_ out?  If your querying code supports it (say, working in Java or .NET), get out an actual `timestamp` type.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff - The data is in the DB that way.  I cannot change it.

Comment: @alfasin select END_DT from DB would result in 10-AUG-07 for the first ID number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to "get" the correct date, you can use something like

```
select 
  substr(to_char(END_DT,'yyyy'),2,1) ||
  substr(to_char(END_DT,'yyyy'),1,1) || 
  substr(to_char(END_DT,'yyyy'),3,2) ||'-'||
  to_char(END_DT,'mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
  as dt
From DB;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following logic should undo the problem, if this is a consistent formatting issue:

```
select (case when left(to_char(END_DT, 'yyyy'), 2) = '02'
             then '20'||substr(to_char(END_DT,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss'), 3, 100)
             else to_char(END_DT,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
        end) as BetterFormat
```

This assumes that the problem is that the first two digits are reversed, and that this did not happen previous to 2000.

However, I must emphasize, the data is incorrect in the database.  The right thing to do is to fix the data in the database.  Covering up the problem might be making things worse in the medium term.

Comment: The problem is that `to_char(END_DT, 'yyyy')` does not resolve to `'02'` but to `0207` or `0208` etc. You'd probably want to use `substr` like Oscar suggested